# Python deployment fails with "packaging 21.2 has requirement pyparsing<3,>=2.0.2, but you have pyparsing 3.0.5."

Tags: python, packaging

Issue in google app engine:
previous deployment 1 week ago was ok, now i get

"packaging 21.2 has requirement pyparsing<3,>=2.0.2, but you have pyparsing 3.0.5."

both packages are not defined in the requirements.txt file.

It looks like a new packaging version 21.2 was deployed automatically.
How to solve this?

Update:
being worked on:

https://github.com/pypa/packaging/pull/482

Answer (score 2):

Manually installing pyparsing 2.4.7 has been reported to work.

I released pyparsing 3.0.6 today, in which I try to accommodate the issues in the packaging code that uses pyparsing. 3.0.6 fails 1 unit test of packaging 21.2 that tests for a specific string in an exception message, but otherwise all tests pass.

Please try installing pyparsing 3.0.6, which should be compatible with packaging 21.2 and later.

[UPDATE] Packaging 21.3 just dropped, so you should be able to upgrade both libraries. It looks like packaging is working on a new parser to replace their pyparsing one, so this will reduce their external dependencies. (I think this has been in their roadmap for a long time, so they are finally getting around to it.)

Comment: Thank you, manually installing pyparsing 2.4.7 fixed the issue on Google App Engine for me until packaging comes out with a new version.

Comment: Packaging 21.3 just dropped, so you should be able to upgrade both libraries.  It looks like packaging is working on a new parser to replace their pyparsing one, so this will reduce their external dependencies. (I think this has been in their roadmap for a long time, so they are finally getting around to it.)

Answer (score 0):

For newcomers this might fix the issue on Ubuntu/Debian based systems.

After I saw that `setup.py` needed `pyparsing` to work I tried to install it manually by `pip3 install pyparsing==2.0.2` but that too needed `pyparsing` lol. So what I did was `sudo apt install python3-pyparsing` and then after it installs the correct version you can use `setup.py` again.